# Need regex to get rid of spam script tag with specific url

Tags: regex

A client's site has been hacked with many injected javascript redirects.  Trying to use regex, find and replace to clean out the database.

The javascript is as follows

```
<script src='https://somelandingpage.com/[variables etc]' async type='text/javascript'></script>
```

There are many of these with different variables, but the core URL is the same.  I'd love to find a pattern to delete all script tags with the URL in that pattern with the variables following?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<script src='https:\/\/somelandingpage\.com.+<\/script>
```